# Sen's $\gamma$ and $\alpha$ imply rationalizability of choice

Tags: economics, binary-operations

I need the proof or a reference for the proof that Sen's $\gamma$ and $\alpha$ imply rationalizability of choice (iff?).

Moreover, on Rubinstein's notes, rationalizability can be shown by Sen's $\alpha$ and the condition that the domain of the choice function contains at least all subsets of X of cardinality 3 or less. I cannot understand this last condition and how it "replaces" Sen's $\gamma$

A brief discussion on the extra assumption implied by Sen's $\beta$, which makes the choice rationalizable under preference relation would be useful.

[I have already posted the question of economics stack, but it seems it is a rather technical question, I didn't get much success]

EDIT
**Def** If $\forall A,B  \subseteq X; x \in C(A) \cap C(B) \Rightarrow x \in C(A \cup B)$, then the choice rule $C(\cdot)$ satisfies Sen’s $\gamma$ Axiom.

Comment: I'm familiar with Sen's $\alpha$ and $\beta$ axioms, but what is Sen's $\gamma$?

Comment: I added the definition in the main question

Comment: What are $S$ and $T$?

Comment: sorry, I fixed the typo

Answer (score 0):

The proof that the Weak Axiom of Revealed Preference (WARP) implies Sen's properties alpha and gamma can be found in ["Incompleteness and Intransitivity"
by Hector Lopez](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~hlopezca/consistency.pdf). Rationalizability is equivalent to the Weak Axiom of Revealed Preference (WARP) ([proof](https://www.pitt.edu/~luca/ECON2100/lecture_02.pdf)).

Answer (score -1):

Axiom $\alpha$ is due to Sen, but $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are due to Herman Chernoff, *Econometrica* 22,4, 1954, 422--43, postulates $5^*$ and 10, respectively.  It is not true that $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ alone imply rational choice; but $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do, and there is a proof in Krep's *Notes on the Theory of Choice*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).